# A black line appears above video after translating

Tags: html, css

So i've a intro animation which should be centered vertically.

I used `top:50%` and `translateY` to center it. In safari a black line appears on top of the video after translating with a %. If I use for example `translateY(-200px)`, the line doesn't appear.

In chrome & firefox, it seems to be good and the line doesn't appear.

There is an example here: http://www.scoutsoverijse.be/test/test.html (here it's not translated) If I don't translate it, the line doesn't appear. It only appears after translating with a % argument.

screenshot of the black line here: http://i58.tinypic.com/nnllht.jpg)

edit: when changing to

```
video {
   display: block
}
```

the line appears on top, with `display:inline` it's at the bottom of the video (not only in safari anymore)

css:

```
.animation {
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <!-- Main content here, which appears trough js, after animation ended -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 animation">
            <video id="introVideo" width="100%" poster="images/fff.png" preload autoplay="autoplay">
                <source src="video/PreLoader.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="video/PreLoader.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="video/PreLoader.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
             Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: **So what have you tried? where is your code?**

Comment: Show me all your css

Comment: I left some non-essential things out:
http://jsfiddle.net/t6mmgu25/2/